# How do I use lazy with an initializer?

Tags: c#, .net, lazy-initialization

I have an array where I initialize its value at declaration time, like this:

```
Foo[] f = Foo[] { new Foo { y = 1 }, new Foo { y = 3 } };
```

How do I use [`lazy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) in this?

*imaginary code*

```
Lazy<Foo[]> f = new Lazy<Foo[]> { new Foo { y = 1 }, new Foo { y = 3 } };
```

Comment: Is the class `Foo` expensive to create? Otherwise you don't need Lazy there

Comment: In my real code it's. And f is a large array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm thinking like this:

```
Lazy<Foo[]> f = new Lazy<Foo[]>(() => new[] { new Foo { y = 1 }, new Foo { y = 3 } });
```